# Is there a way to create a filter expression in MongoDB C# drivers (same way as projection allows)?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I can create a projection fiel definition from expression like that:

```cs
var projection = Builders<Bar>.Projection.Expression(x => x.Foo)
```

I want to do exactly the same with the filter:

```cs
var filter = Builders<Bar>.Filter.Expression(x => x.Foo == "10")
```

But I cannot find a way to do this. The operations that I want to perform `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` supports an expression as it's input directly, but I want to combine a "hardcoded" filter with the one that is coming in as a parameter. This is how I do it now without an expression:

```cs
var filter = Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id); // Here I would like to write Filter.Expression(x => x.Id == id)
if (additionalFilter != null)
{
    filter &= additionalFilter;
}
```

P.S. I would rather avoid combining expressions directly "the C# way" as it is not very easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo net driver does not support `Filter.Expression` and if you want to project any value cast to as  `ToList`
See the below eg:

```
 var filter = Builders<Movie>.Filter.In("cast", new string[] { "Tom Hanks" });
 var movies = await _moviesCollection.Find<Movie>(filter)
                .Limit(2)
                .ToListAsync();

// your test

var projection = Builders<Bar>.Projection.Expression(x => x.Foo);
    var projection = Builders<Bar>.Filter.Where(x => x.Foo == "10");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I did not really need to cast to List, but rather join to various filters

Comment: Sure, you can filter it but `Filter` in mongo net driver supports `Where`, `In` , and `Eq`. In your case, you can use `Where`.

Comment: I see, thanks, that is actually what I was looking for :) I just did not get it right away from your answer